# Unable to Reflectively Instantiate a "protected" class of an "opened" package, from another module

Tags: java, reflection, java-module, java-platform-module-system

### Summary

I'm unable to reflectively instantiate a class across module boundaries. The class has package-level access, and I'm trying to instantiate it from not just outside the package, but from outside the module itself. According to my understanding, I'm allowed to do this, so long as the containing package has been `open`ed by the containing module, and the instantiating module `requires` the containing module. All I get for my attempted instantiation is an `IllegalAccessException`

### Details

My app is configured as a "Modular Java project" in my Netbeans 11, and is configured to run on the Java 12 platform.

In the app, I have two modules:

- `mod.world`
- `mod.vehicles`

`mod.world` is my "main" module -- it has the `main()` method, and it declares that it `requires` the other module `mod.vehicles`

`mod.vehicles` defines a "protected" class (a class with package-level access) called `vehicles.cars.Sedan`, in package `vehicles.cars`

`mod.vehicles` declares that it `opens vehicles.cars`

In the `main()` method, I attempt to instantiate the `Sedan` class, using:

```
var myConstructor = Class.forName("vehicles.cars.Sedan").
                                        getDeclaredConstructor();

myConstructor.newInstance();
```

### What I Expect to See

I expect that the code successfully instantiates the `Sedan` class, and the `println()` inside the `Sedan` constructor gets executed.

### What I Actually Get

But this invocation of `newInstance()` throws an `IllegalAccessException`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class
>   world.MyMainClass (in module mod.world) cannot access a member of
>   class vehicles.cars.Sedan (in module mod.vehicles) with modifiers
>   "public"

### My Questions

According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/jls12.pdf) (section 7.7.2 Exported and Opened Packages):

> The opens directive specifies the name of a package to be opened by
>   the current module. For code in other modules, this grants access at
>   run time, but not compile time, to the public and protected types in
>   the package, and the public and protected members of those types. **It
>   also grants reflective access to all types in the package, and all
>   their members, for code in other modules**.

1. My understanding of the above extract from the JLS is that I should
   be able to access the "protected" type `Sedan`, and its members,
   which includes the constructor. But why am I not able to use that
   constructor to instantiate the `Sedan` class reflectively?
2. Which part of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/jls12.pdf) am I violating by
   attempting this instantiation?
3. Is my understanding of the term **reflective access** wrong? Is this term defined formally somewhere by Java? Couldn't find a formal definition of *reflective access* anywhere in the JLS for Java 12.

### Here's the complete code:

---

**`module-info.java` for the `mod.world` module:**

```
module mod.world {
    exports world;
    requires mod.vehicles;
}
```

---

**`MyMainClass.java`, in package `world` of module `mod.world`:**

```
package world;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class MyMainClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
                                                NoSuchMethodException,
                                                InstantiationException,
                                                IllegalAccessException,
                                                InvocationTargetException {

        // This statement succeeds.
        var myConstructor = Class.forName("vehicles.cars.Sedan").
                                                getDeclaredConstructor();

        // This statement throws IllegalAccessException
        myConstructor.newInstance();
    }
}
```

---

**`module-info.java` for the `mod.vehicles` module:**

```
module mod.vehicles {
    opens vehicles.cars;
}
```

---

**`Sedan.java` in package `vehicles.cars`:**

```
package vehicles.cars;

class Sedan {
    public Sedan () {
        System.out.println ("Inside constructor Sedan()");
    }
}
```

---

### Other Observation

The instantiation goes through successfully if I change the `Sedan` class to a `public` one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Sedan` is package-private, you need to call [`myConstructor.setAccessible​(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#setAccessible(boolean)).

`opens` is what allows to you to call `setAccessible​`, it doesn't eliminate the need for the call.

Comment: I find it a bit non-intuitive, that I need to call the `setAccessible()` on the **_constructor_** of the `Sedan` class, to deal with the in-accessibility of the `Sedan` class itself. IMHO, it would've made more sense for the API to provide a `Class.setAccessible()` method for this situation.

Comment: I also find it non-intuitive, that despite the in-accessibility of the `Sedan` class I'm able to do`Class.forName(strClassName).getDeclaredConstructor()`

Comment: you should now use `.trySetAccessible` on java 9+, and yea, it's kinda legacy thing now after adding modules to java, for me it's still very weird that you need to open module to allow for reflections, that should be `setAccessible` job only.